# Removing ' ' and returning the list items without ' ' - Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list,  List = [ 'A', 'B', 'C']

I want to return this List and print the items without '  '

```
def  returnTheList():
     List = [ ]
     #dosomething here
     .....
     return List

print returnTheList
```

My output is

```
['A','B','C']
```

I would like something like this as the output in my *main.py*

```
A
B
C
```

EDIT: I do not want to print in the function itself, rather in my main function. This list will be *returned* by the function and the caller gets a non-braces items.

Answer (score 2):

```
print '\n'.join(returnTheList())
```

You can print line-by-line using this. Please note that this is applicable only to strings; if you have mixed e.g. integers and strings use

```
print '\n'.join(map(str, returnTheList()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in returnTheList():
    print item
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a simple iteration through the list. (Also, avoid using List/list as variable names since they are python-reserved keywords):

```
lst = [...]

for i in lst:
    print(i)
```